How to restore a previous state of a GridLayout in Kotlin after screen rotation?
So I am working on an App to keep track of scores in games. The scores are arranged in a GridLayout with playernames on top and the a count for the round number on the side. All information gets stored in a Room database. For example every cell has a CellId, GameInstanceId, playerId, roundNumber and the value itself. So if i have the gameInstanceId I can theoretically recreate the whole scoresheet. The problem now is I am apparently too stupid to recreate a state of the scoresheet after for example a screen rotation or any other event that leads to a new loading of the activity. Can someone help me how i can rebuild a previous state out of my data in the database. Inserting/editing/retrieving data from the database is not an issue and works perfectly fine everytime.
I tried to rebuild the onCreate function for the event if the screen rotates or any other event because in the onCreate the scoresheet gets built correctly and rows are getting added dynamically if the previous row is filled with values. So i thought i could use this code in some form to rebuild the scoresheet but currently i am just able to display the previous values but i cannot enter new values (I attached new clicklisteners but I am getting foreign key issues) and editing previous values also doesnt work (maybe clicklistener not properly attached to previous values)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Let your Room Dao return Flows. Just wrap the return types in a Flow<...> and Room will automatically create flows under the hood. Your view model then transforms the Dao flows to flows of simple UI state objects and presents them to the UI where the flows are eventually collected.
With this, the activity subscribes to the flows when they are needed (when the activity is created or resumed) and unsubscribes when the activity is paused or destroyed. The view model will survive the lifecycle of the activity, so the flows - and therefore the data to be displayed - stay intact on configuration changes like screen rotations.
